# Installing C POSIX libraies in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, programming, libraries, c

I'm trying to install the following C POSIX headers in Ubuntu 14.04 but for some reason some of them won't install.

1. `sys/ioctl.h`
2. `unistd.h`
3. `locale.h`
4. `ncursesw/ncurses.h`

**Commands tried**

```
sudo apt-get install sys/ioctl.h
sudo apt-get install unistd.h
sudo apt-get install locale.h
sudo apt-get install ncursesw/ncruses.h
```

I've only managed to install `locale.h` but for some reason the rest return a regex error stating that `sys/ioctl.h` wasn't found. I'm fairly new to Linux/Ubuntu and are not sure what to do at this point. Any help is appreciated

Comment: FWIW only some of these headers provide interfaces described by POSIX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more googling, I realized that what I had to do was to install the packages that contained the libraries I was interested in. It wasn't long before I stumbled across these two websites;

1. [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com)
2. [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?mode=filename&suite=wheezy&section=all&arch=i386&searchon=contents&keywords=locale.h)

There you will find the packages of many many libraries. And you can install from any package you want!

Comment: yep, there is a similar site provided Ubuntu, http://packages.ubuntu.com/ , you may [edit] your answer to point to Ubuntu one. BTW, could you accept your own answer as that what works for you, see http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer & http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

The things you have listed are *header files* - which do not have a one-to-one correspondence with Ubuntu (Debian) *packages*.

In particular, `sys/ioctl.h` and `sys/unistd.h` should both be provided by the `libc6-dev` package and `ncursesw/ncurses.h` by the `libncursesw5-dev` package i.e.

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev libncursesw5-dev
```

If you haven't already installed the GCC compiler, you can install the `build-essential` metapackage which includes the compilers as well as `libc6-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libncursesw5-dev
```

Comment: Also, if you are trying to build a particular package (say `mutt`), `sudo apt-get build-dep mutt` may be what you really want.